# How to edit the Firebase DynamicLinks 404 (Dynamic Link Not Found) page?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase DynamicLinks and wondering if there is a way to edit the page that appears when the user opens an invalid or deleted link?

I tried to provide the 404.html in the public folder of Firebase hosting but didn't work as expected.

[image: I wanna edit what appears in this image]

Comment: I also want to know about the same. I have index.html and 404.html. If I hit the dynamic link domain then the index.html page is shown but if the dynamic link is invalid then the 404.html page is not shown. It redirects to some "Dynamic link not found" page.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old post, I will drop an answer here anyway, as this question is the first result when using searching for this in Google.

**Short answer:** It's not possible.

**Long answer:** Theoretically, it should be possible by [creating and adding a 404.html to your public directory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#404). However, as I tried it out on my own project, and turns out it doesn't work for dynamic links.

Perhaps someone hopes that creating a dynamical magical page with a wildcard path will help and firebase will overwrite it. No, it won't. I added a file for my FAQ page at `doma.in/faq` (`faq.html` in `/public` directory) and then tried adding a dynamic link for the very same link. The original faq.html was served.

I will update if I figure something out.

Comment: did you find anything? Any idea how you can change the homepage? For example the page served at doma.in ?

Comment: This kinda really sucks that there is no way to redirect not found dynamic links!

Comment: Anyone figure anything out?